# What is the meaning of the number in parens after the names of shell commands in the title of a manpage?

Tags: shell, manpage

I see these numbers everywhere. For example, on this page: http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar

What is the meaning of the number - `1` in `tar(1)` ? I have seen 2, 5, etc also.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It tells you what group its manpage is in or, more generally, which group the item itself belongs to. Here's a list of the sections and their contents:

```
   1   Executable programs or shell commands
   2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
   3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
   4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
   5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
   6   Games
   7   Miscellaneous  (including  macro  packages  and  conventions), e.g.
       man(7), groff(7)
   8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
   9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
```

See the manpage of 'man' for more details. Or have a look here:
http://linux.die.net/man/

Sometimes items from different groups can have the same name and this is the way to distinguish between them. For example, there is a manpage for **printf(1)** which is an executable, callable from a shell, as well as a manpage for **printf(3)** which is a C function definded in stdio.h.

Using the man binary from a bash you can call for the distinct manpages by:

```
man printf       # displays printf(1)
man 1 printf     # displays printf(1)
man 3 prinft     # displays printf(3)
man -a printf    # displays all manpages matching printf
```

Depending on what manpages are installed on the system you sometimes get pages from different manuals for the same item. For example **printf(3)** from the Linux Programmer's Manual could have a **printf(3p)** counterpart from the Posix Programmer's manual.